# Move Object and Viewport

Tags: jquery, arrow-keys

So I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/PT22R/3/

It works great but I'd like to be able to move the viewport while the player moves so that I can fully see the object on the side.

This is what I want to have when I move the player with the left arrow key:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vsq6.png

```
case 37:
        // add something here?
        $div.css('left', $div.offset().left - 10);
```

Rather than just moving the player and keeping the object halfway hidden like it already is.

This should be simple enough, I'm just not sure what to call for. 
P.S: I'd also like to keep the `overflow: hidden`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Do you want to move the viewport instead of the square?

Comment: you can rather make it "look like" the whole screen moves

Comment: Anyone else click on the image, press the arrow keys and wonder why it didn't move?  Oops!

Comment: @johnSmith as long as I get the desired result I'll be fine :)

Comment: @giorgio Yes! That was the word I was looking for.

Comment: so you dont move the box that "moves" but you move every other object arround, then you have this effect

Comment: Thx John, but I had tried that before and guessed that it would be really annoying for future uses, I'm sure that there's an easier way to do this.

Comment: is that what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/PT22R/4/

Comment: Yes but I'd like to keep the `overflow: hidden`